# How to create empty entries for every day of the week for all weeks

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table containing some event data. It looks as follows:

```
+------+-----------+--------+
| Week |   day     | value1 |
+------+-----------+--------+
|    2 | Monday    |      5 |
|    2 | Thursday  |      2 |
|    2 | Sunday    |      1 |
|    3 | Monday    |      2 |
|    3 | Tuesday   |      2 |
|    3 | Wednesday |      0 |
|    3 | Thursday  |      9 |
|    9 | Friday    |      3 |
+------+-----------+--------+
```

Now I would like for every week in this table, to have entries for every day of the week. If they don't exist, it has to be unfilled. Like so:

```
+------+-----------+--------+
| Week |   day     | value1 |
+------+-----------+--------+
|    2 | Monday    | 5      |
|    2 | Tuesday   | Null   |
|    2 | Wednesday | Null   |
|    2 | Thursday  | 2      |
|    2 | Friday    | Null   |
|    2 | Saturday  | Null   |
|    2 | Sunday    | 1      |
+------+-----------+--------+
```

etc.

What I tried so far is to take all the weeks in the table, cross join them with a list of all days in a week and then right join that on the week, with no success.

The reason for this whole exercise is that I can obtain a delta table with the difference between weeks, per day of value1.

All tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have values for every day in the table, then:

```
select w.week, d.day, t.value1
from (select distinct week from t) w cross join
     (select distinct day from t) d left join
     t
     on t.week = w.week and t.day = d.day
order by t.week, array_position(array['Monday', 'Tuesday', . . . ], d.day);
```

If you don't have  all seven days in the table, you can generate them:

```
select w.week, d.day, t.value1
from (select distinct week from t) w cross join
     (values (1, 'Monday'), (2, 'Tuesday'), . .     
     ) d(ord, day) left join
     t
     on t.week = w.week and t.day = d.day
order by w.week, d.ord;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @timmaay92 . . . If this (or any other answer) answers your question, then you should accept it.  Note that you can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try next solution in case your table have unique week+day constraint:

```
-- insert results into your table
insert into table (
  -- select combined weeks and days table
  select "day", "week", null "value1" from (
    -- select weeks from range. For example it 1..52 
    select * from generate_series(1, 52) as "week"
  ) a 
  cross join (
    -- select day from array of days.
    select unnest (array['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunaday']) as "day"
  ) t) 
-- prevent rows duplication
on conflict do nothing ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE event_data (
    date date,
    value int
);
```

you can do

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    generate_series('2020-jan-1'::date, '2020-jan-15'::date, '1 day') AS date
    LEFT OUTER JOIN event_data USING (date);
```

and then extract the week number and weekday and do the formatting.